# How does apache webserver "decide" what content to serve when no virtual hosts are configured?

Tags: server, apache2, webserver

I am trying to debug some weird behaviour on an apache 2.4 install on Ubuntu 14.04 server.
I notice if I remove all virtual hosts and additional configurations by commenting out their `IncludeOptional` lines from the `apache.conf` config file, e.g.

```
File: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

# DISABLE generic snippets of statements
# IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# DISABLE the virtual host configurations:
# IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

(Then restart apache)

If I browse to the server apache will still serve content from `/var/www`.

My question is, how or where is apache being "told" to use that as a document root?

- is it some ultimate fall back `DocumentRoot` that is compiled into apache itself?
- Ive looked in the apache configuration files and I can't find any `DocumentRoot = /var/www` directives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an ultimate fallback `DocumentRoot` location. From [the Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot):

```
Default:    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache/htdocs
```

However, for packaging, the default is changed to `/var/www` (since packages aren't supposed to reside in or use `/usr/local`). The particular patch that does this is `fhs_compliance.patch`:

```
--- a/include/httpd.h
+++ b/include/httpd.h
@@ -109,7 +109,7 @@
 #define DOCUMENT_LOCATION  HTTPD_ROOT "/docs"
 #else
 /* Set default for non OS/2 file system */
-#define DOCUMENT_LOCATION  HTTPD_ROOT "/htdocs"
+#define DOCUMENT_LOCATION  "/var/www"
 #endif
 #endif /* DOCUMENT_LOCATION */
```

You can examine the full patch by downloading it (`apt-get source apache2; cd apache2*; less debian/patches/fhs_compliance.patch`) or online at [Debian's packaging Git repository](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-apache/apache2.git/tree/debian/patches/fhs_compliance.patch).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you don't have a `DocumentRoot` directive in your configuration a compiled in default value is used. In Ubuntu before 14.10 it's `/var/www`, in 14.10 this has been changed to `/var/www/html`.

Comment: "In Ubuntu before 14.10 it's /var/www, in 14.10 this has been changed to /var/www/html" --> This sentence would be more readable like: "On older Ubuntu version, this path was `/var/www`, being changed on Ubuntu 14.10 to `/var/www/html`"